# GET & POST passing parameters

Tags: rest, http, post, get, x-www-form-urlencoded

I've read many question on stackoverflow about passing parameters with GET and POST methods, but none of them satisfied my curiosity.

I use GETs to retrieve data passing parameters as path/query params and use POSTs to save data passing parameters as request body with Content-Type: application/json and sometimes request body + path/query params (depending on other APIs I've created for simmetry purpose only).

My question is when to use Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Say I want to call a POST without a request body of Content-Type: application/json but with params, do I have to use the application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type or I can use path/query params as best practice?

What's the difference between sending data as path/query params and key-value params with  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded? Does the data size have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between sending data as path/query params and key-value params with Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Consider this example

```
PUT /example?a=b&c=d
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

d=e&f=g
```

What's happening here?  This is a request that the server replace its current representation of the resource identified by

```
/example?a=b&c=d
```

With the payload.  In other words, after successful processing, we would expect

```
GET /example?a=b&c=d
```

to produce a response like

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

d=e&f=g
```

---

```
POST /example?a=b&c=d
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

d=e&f=g
```

For POST, it's the same idea, except that instead of "replace the current representation", POST stands in for "process the payload according to the specific semantics of /example?a=b&c=d".

---

> GETs to retrieve data passing parameters as path/query params

It might help to reframe your thinking here.  We use GET to retrieve the current representation of a resource.  We aren't passing parameters, we're passing a document (resource) identifier.

The fact that the origin server's implementation is going to parse that identifier is an implementation detail.

> A URI Template is a compact sequence of characters for describing a
> range of Uniform Resource Identifiers through variable expansion.
> -- [RFC 6570](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570)

---

> I want to call a POST without a request body of Content-Type: application/json but with params, do I have to use the application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type or I can use path/query params as best practice?

```
POST /example?a=b&c=d
Content-Type: application/json

{"d":"e","f":"g"}
```

Is a perfectly normal HTTP request.

[Content-Type](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-8.3) describes the payload only - it has nothing at all to do with the target URI, and how information might be encoded within it.

Comment: Ok. Then, I don't understand the difference between sending {"d":"e","f":"g"} (application/json) and d=e&f=g (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) in POSTs.
I use to create POSTs with request body in json format while application/x-www-form-urlencoded only for auth APIs.